# Chebyshev polynomials and trace of $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

> Defining $C_n(z) = \frac{z^m + z^{-m}}{2}$, the Chebyshev polynomials are defined by
>
> $$T_n(C_1(z)) = C_n(z)$$
>   and are given by $T_1(z) = z, T_2(z) = 2z^2-1, T_3(z) = 4z^3-3z$, etc. Since for $z=e^{i\theta}$ we have $C_1(z) = \cos\theta$, they also satisfy
>
> $$T_n(\cos\theta) = \cos(n\theta)$$
>
> thereby generalizing the double angle trig identity.

The notes I'm reading also claim $$T_n(\text{tr } A/2) = \text{tr } (A^n/2)$$ for $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Why does this follow?

*Attempt: if $A= \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c &d \end{pmatrix}$ then choosing $z=\frac12(\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4}- (a+d))$ implies $C_1(z) = \text{tr }A/2$, but then $T_n(C_1(z)) = \frac{z^n+z^{-n}}{2}$ does not simplify as far as I see to $\text{tr} A^n/2$.*

Comment: Note that the trace of $A$ is the sum of its eigenvalues and the product of its eigenvalues is by definition $1$.

Comment: @WimC thanks, that resolves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several sources with a proof, e.g., the paper by [Francis Bonahon](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07617.pdf), Lemma $8$ on page $9$, using Cayley-Hamilton. Another interesting reference is the paper by [Traina](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2043068?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) on trace polynomials for $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.